# Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loginButton: '',
        benchmarkList: ''
    }
    if (props.username == null) {
        this.state.loginButton = <GoogleButton></GoogleButton>
    } else {

    }
}
```

It is giving me an ESLint warning:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state.

Now what am I supposed to do as I can't use `setState` inside `constructor` directly as it creates [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488195/why-does-react-throw-an-error-when-setstate-method-used-in-a-class-constructor) and updating like this gives me error.

Comment: Setting `this.state` doesn't have to be the first statement; you can set all kinds of `var`s first, then use those to compose `this.state`.

Comment: Just gonna toss this out here that storing a React component in state is probably not the best direction to go

Comment: Indeed, a better solution is to use `{ !this.state.username && <GoogleButton /> }` in your render object.

Comment: @rossipedia And why is that, will it slow down rendering or state change detection?

Comment: While there's nothing _technically_ preventing you from doing that, it goes against the convention of having all your UI logic inside your `render()` method. I can't remember off the top of my head, but there are a few other gotchas I remember reading about, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, **we should not store the ui components inside state variable**, state should contain only data. All the ui part should be inside `render` method.

If you want to `render` some component on the basis of any data then use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html). Check the value of `this.state.loginButton` and if it is `null` then render that button.

Like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loginButton: props.username,
        benchmarkList: ''
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {!this.state.loginButton ? <GoogleButton></GoogleButton> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ideally we should not store the `props` value in `state` also, so directly use `this.props.username`, i did that because don't know about the complete code.

Comment: Ok. I see your point of using conditional in views. But why on earth will I store a props property into state property when that property will only be controlled by parent only?

Comment: @JennaWesley man, i just showed the better way, don't know about your complete code. You should not store that `props` in `state` also, use directly by `this.props.username`.

Comment: i thought may be you are updating that value somewhere in this component that's why.

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot and already implemented the techniques of this answer

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loginButton: props.username == null? <GoogleButton></GoogleButton>: '',
      benchmarkList: ''
    }
  }
```

Or You can use setState in `componentWillMount()`

```
componentWillMount(){
   let loginButton = props.username == null? <GoogleButton></GoogleButton>: '';
   this.setState({loginButton: loginButton});
}
```

Comment: The first way will end up making the code messy but yeah I can do something similar. Prepare the variables first and then `this.state = ...`

Comment: The question is about `constructor` however the `componentWillMount` is good place.

Answer (score 0):

> How to update state inside `constructor` in ReactJS?

Create the data struct, modify it as need, and assign to state at the end when all is done:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    let state = {
        loginButton: '',
        benchmarkList: ''
    }
    if (props.username == null) {
        state.loginButton = true
    } else {
        state.loginButton = false
    }
    this.state = state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add setState

```
if (props.username == null) {

       this.setState({
            loginButton: <GoogleButton></GoogleButton>
       })

} else {
```